# MySQL Query, I want to select the latest row for each person

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table

```
id|name|number|date
1|peter|2|2017-09-18
2|peter|1|2017-10-03
3|james|4|2017-09-05
4|james|1|2017-10-10
5|james|0|2017-10-15
6|kate|4|2017-09-16
7|kate|2|2017-10-17
```

I want to select the latest row for each person (the row with the latest date). The result will look like

```
2|peter|1|2017-10-03
5|james|0|2017-10-15
7|kate|2|2017-10-17
```

Which MYSQL query can do that?

Something like :

```
SELECT id, name, number, date 
FROM table 
GROUP BY id, name, number, date 
HAVING date the latest
```

Comment: What qualifies as "*the most actual row*" for each person?

Comment: Do you mean the *latest* date?

Comment: Yes, I mean the latest date. I am sorry for my English.

Comment: But wouldn't that give you an output of the `second` row for Peter? In your 'desired result', you showcase him having an ID of one.

Comment: The question is very common. See many other answers by reading [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.* from table t1, (select t2.name name2, max(t2.date) 
date2 from table t2 group by t2.name) t3 where t1.name = t3.name2 and t1.date = t3.date2
```

Comment: It says "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error :(

Comment: Please add a short explanation

Comment: Ok, please Try the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM persons WHERE name='someone' order by date desc limit 1`

This works well for selecting lastest entity by specified name.

`SELECT * FROM persons GROUP BY name, date ORDER BY date DESC`

I wrote this with my mobile, something can be wrong, but its concepts will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from stack s1 where s1.d = (select max(s2.d) 
from stack s2 where s2.name = s1.name);
+------+-------+------+------------+
| id   | name  | num  | d          |
+------+-------+------+------------+
|    2 | peter |    1 | 2017-10-03 |
|    5 | james |    0 | 2017-10-15 |
|    7 | kate  |    2 | 2017-10-17 |
+------+-------+------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And for large datasets, don't forget to add indexes to 'name' and 'd' columns.